# Delphi Rest Server and Sencha

Tags: delphi, rest, extjs

Created a Rest server in Delphi, there I have the method: GetJSONCustomer :     TJSONValue ; which returns me a JSON value. Browser, if I type :  my_url/GetJSONCustomer works correct.

I'm trying to integrate ExtJS 4 to try and read this address, but is placed in front of the link thereby :  my_url/GetJSONCustomer/?_dc=1400273585013&page=1&start=0&limit=25/ al and the browser returns me an error Status  Code : 409 Conflict.

In Extjs I did so:

```
Ext.define('Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'email',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});

Ext.define('ContatosStore' {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Contact',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',

        api: {
            read: 'url_gose_here'
        },

        reader: {
            type: 'json', //json or xml
            root: 'contacts'
        },

        writer: {
            type: 'json', //json or xml
            root: 'customer.TCustomer'
            writeAllFields: true,
            encode: true,
            allowSingle: true
        }
    }
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true
});

Ext.onReady(function () {
    var store = Ext.create('ContatosStore');
    //console.log(store.data);
    store.on('load', function (s) {
        console.log(s.data);
        //.............
    });
    //.............
});
```

Where my code is wrong ?

Thanks Charles